# What's the best solution for Hosted Exchange?

Tags: exchange, hosted-exchange

I've looked at WSP and was wondering if there are any other solutions for setting up hosted exchange to resell?

Answer (score 1):

If by WSP you mean Website Panel, I can tell you that the 3 most popular control panel vendors in the Exchange hosted space are [ExtendASP](http://www.extendasp.com/), [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/spp/microsoftapps/), and [Ensim](http://www.ensim.com/products/ensim_unify/unify_service_provider_edition/index.html). Equally popular for larger hosting companies is to write their own. The hosted Exchange space is heavily overloaded right now; most smaller outfits looking to host are wisely choosing to use a white label service instead of building their own.